# How to use @Binding when view is creating using function in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created view using Function and which i am calling from another view (AbcView), I want to perform normal `@Binding` with that, but not sure how to pass value and create `@Binding` in function.

In Below code I want to pass `selectedPassengerId` from `AbcView` to function `topSheetClassViews` and perform @Binding whenever value `passengerIds` in `SelectedTitleView` is updating so that I can get updated value in `AbcView`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AbcView: View {

    @StateObject var abcViewModel: AbcViewModel
    @State private var selectedPassengerId: Int?

    init(accessibiltyID: String, abcViewModel: AbcViewModel) {
        self._abcViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: abcViewModel)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            // Some Design
        }
        .overlay(
            TopView((accessibilityID: accessibilityID, content: topSheetClassViews(abcViewModel: abcViewModel), selectedRowID: $selectedPassengerId, rowHeight: $rowHeight),, alignment: .top
                   )
        )
    }
}



func topSheetClassViews(abcViewModel: AbcViewModel) -> [AnyView] {
    var views: [AnyView] = []

    for passenger in 0..<abcViewModel.Passengers.count {
        views.append(TopSheetPassengerInfoView(abcViewModel: abcViewModel, index: passenger).convertToAnyView())
    }
    return views
}

struct SelectedTitleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var abcViewModel: AbcViewModel
    var passengerIds: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("passengerIds \(passengerIds)") // here getting correct id which I want to pass to AbcView
            Text(abcViewModel.passengerTitle(passengerId: passengerIds))
        }
    }
}

struct TopSheetPassengerInfoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var abcViewModel: AbcViewModel
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text(abcViewModel.passengers[index].fullName ?? "")
            SelectedTitleView(abcViewModel: abcViewModel, passengerIds: Int(abcViewModel.Passengers[index].passengerId ?? "") ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid `AnyView`. You are using the function `topSheetClassViews` to append instances of the same type `TopSheetPassengerInfoView`: change your code, by creating a view called `TopSheetClassViews` that iterates over the passengers, using `ForEach` to show different `TopSheetPassengerInfoView`.

Comment: `Binding<>` is just a regular type, inject as binding variable via function arguments.

Comment: @Asperi is that possible in my code..because its not like regular where we pass parameter to next view..here I am passing to function which is using from another view..Can you help me with code if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it through everywhere you need to pass it, like

here

```
func topSheetClassViews(abcViewModel: AbcViewModel, selection: Binding<Int?>) -> [AnyView] {
```

here

```
views.append(TopSheetPassengerInfoView(abcViewModel: abcViewModel, selectedID: selection, index: passenger).convertToAnyView())
```

here

```
struct TopSheetPassengerInfoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var abcViewModel: AbcViewModel
    @Binding var selectedID: Int?
```

and so on